# PHP compile string to bytecode without evaling it

Tags: php, python

Python (CPython and Jython at least, possibly all Pythons) have a function called `compile` that can be used to compile a file into a string into or a bytecode object.

```
# foo.py
a = compile("""
print(47)
""", filename="testfile", mode="exec")

exec(a)
```

Running `foo.py` produces:

```
$ python foo.py
47
```

Does PHP (Zend specifically, any version) expose its bytecode compiler to user code in a similar way? More specifically, can you dynamically compile strings without executing them like `eval` does.

Comment: something like: http://php.net/manual/en/book.bcompiler.php

Comment: Not without an extension like above, but as exec in python is like eval in PHP, you could make a compile() function which returns what you gave it :/, pass it PHP code and it returns the same string, store it in a variable and then use eval. So essentially the same as what your doing with python. You can store php in variable you know?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know but what you show me it's very familiar to this alternative you can improvise:

### foo.php

```
<?php
    print(47);
?>
```

---

### index.php

```
<?php
    include('foo.php');
?>
```

---

eg: so in php cli under windows cmd:

### in any folder you have index.php and foo.php with xampp from apachefriends.org installed in c:\xampp  create runme.bat

```
@echo off
set parameter=%1
set PHP_BIN="c:\xampp\php\php.exe"
%PHP_BIN% %parameter%
```

---

so from cmd you can call very easy cli interpretation of index.php :

```
runme index.php
```

### also runme foo.php had the same results ,the only reason i put there index.php is to use it as a "proxy" between a somehow array list i store in and to include not only foo.php but manny others and in this way could became a kind of "controller" with not much modifies(if the question is pointing to sort of code executions in any order ordered by a kind of controller)

47

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether PHP has the compile builtin function to compile the PHP code, there is no. PHP is a interpreted language, PHP code need interpreter to run it, and the interpreter has the executing environment for it.

But if you want to realize your requirement, here is some way to achieve it:

1. [PHC](https://github.com/pbiggar/phc%20%20)

> phc is an open source compiler for PHP with support for plugins. In addition, it can be used to pretty-print or obfuscate PHP code, as a framework for developing applications that process PHP scripts, or to convert PHP into XML and back, enabling processing of PHP scripts using XML tools.

2. [bcompiler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bcompiler.php)

> To encode entire script in a proprietary PHP application
>   To encode some classes and/or functions in a proprietary PHP application
>   To enable the production of php-gtk applications that could be used on client desktops, without the need for a php.exe.
>   To do the feasibility study for a PHP to C converter

3.[Project Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Zero)

It supports the PHP compile.